# Partial view disapear when form submit ajax.beginform

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

i want to ask how can i retain my partial view when submit my form using Ajax.Beginform...my partial view disappear when i submit my form

here it is code

```html
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("HardwareProblem", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div>
        <div id="ErroDiv" class="message-error" style="position:absolute;"> </div>
        <div id="successDiv" class="message-success" style="position:absolute;"> </div>

        <ul class="po_btn_l1">
            <li><a href="#" class="btn print">Print Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn pop-up">Pop-up Complete List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn screen-shot">Screen Shot</a></li>
            <li>

                @Html.TextBox("Search PO_No", "Goto PO #", new { @class = "po_search" })
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="po_btn_l2">
            <li><input type="submit" value="Save & Exit" class="btn save-exit"></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn discard-changes">Discard Changes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn delete">Delete</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn cancel">Cancle</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="ca-dbhdng" style="width:96%; height :5px; padding:0px;">
        @*<i class="dash-ico-b"></i><h2 style="color: #21355c; font-size:11px;"> Dashboard > Purchase Order</h2>*@
    </div>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <table class="tbl-barcode" style="width: 959px; float: left; padding-bottom: 20PX; ">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="number">01.</span></td>
                    <td class="label-text">
                        <label> GulfIT PO # : </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GulfItPO_NO,
                                                            new { @class = "text-field-search validate[required]" })
                        <input type="button" value="Search" id="Get_Po_Data" class="po_searchm" />
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PO_ID, new { @type = "hidden", @id = "PO_ID" })
                    </td>
                    <td><span>04.</span></td>
                    <td class="label-text">
                        <label>Current Laptop Department:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Laptop_PO_Qty, new { @class = "text-field-readonly validate[required]", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="spaceUnder">
                    <td><span class="number">02.</span></td>
                    <td class="label-text">
                        <label> Laptop Serial No: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Laptop_Sr_No,
                                                            new { @class = "text-field-search validate[required]" })
                        <input type="button" value="Search" id="Get_Laptop_SrNO" class="po_searchm" />
                        @Html.TextBox("PO_ID", "", new { @type = "hidden", @id = "PO_ID" })
                    </td>
                    <td><span>05.</span></td>
                    <td class="label-text">
                        <label>Shift to Department:</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="Delivery_Stauts_ID" class="dropdown">
                            <option>Select</option>
                            <option>Received</option>
                            <option>Labchecking</option>
                            <option>Workshop Repair</option>
                            <option>Paint Shop</option>
                            <option>Ready For Sale</option>
                            <option>Sold</option>
                            <option>Stor For Parts</option>
                            <option>Scrap Laptop </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span class="number">03.</span></td>
                    <td class="label-text">
                        <label> Gulf It BarCode: </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Crnt_GulgIt_Barcode,
                                                            new { @class = "text-field-search validate[required]" })
                        <input type="button" value="Search" id="Get_Crnt_Barcode_Data" class="po_searchm" />
                        @Html.TextBox("PO_ID", "", new { @type = "hidden", @id = "PO_ID" })
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Update and Move" class="btn save-exit">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="ca-dbhdng" style="width:96%; height :5px; padding:0px;">
            @*<i class="dash-ico-b"></i><h2 style="color: #21355c; font-size:11px;"> Dashboard > Purchase Order</h2>*@
        </div>

        <div id="wp-hardware_problem1">
       
       
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

```html
       [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult HardwareProblem(WH_Hardware_Problem_Model REC)
        {  
            
            
            /// inserting my partial view form code
         
           
            return View();
        }
```

Here its Partial view

```html
@model EStock.Models.WorkShop.WH_Hardware_Problem_Model



<ul style="width: 958px; margin-top: 10px;">
    <li style="display:inline-block;"><h2>Hardware Problem Noted</h2></li>
    <li style="float:right;"><input type="submit" value="Update All" class="btn save-exit"></li>
</ul>

<ul class="wp-hpn-headings">

    <li style="width:170px; padding-left:0px;"><h3>Part Name</h3> </li>
    <li><h3>Problem</h3><i>(Spoted by Lab)</i></li>
    <li><h3>Solved</h3> (Yes or No)</li>
    <li><h3>Reason</h3></li>
</ul>

@{int count = 1;
      }
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl.Count; i++)
{
    <ul class="wp-ps-listing bg-white">
        <li class="w_p_z">
           
            @count<span>.</span>
            <h3>
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].HardwarePartID)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].PartName, Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].PartName)
            </h3>
        </li>
        <li>
        
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].nature_of_prob, Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].nature_of_prob)</li>
        <li>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model=>Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].ProblemSolved_Status,"1")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].ProblemSolved_Status, "2")
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].ProblemSolved_Status, "3")
        </li>
     
        <li style="width:290px;">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].Reason, Model.WH_HardwareProblem_Dtl[i].Reason)
          @*  <input type="text" class="text-field" />*@
        </li>
    </ul>
    count++;
}
```

my partial view disappear when i submit form..how am i able to show **strong text**

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see you're not calling your partial view in your parental(main) view.

Like this:

```
<div>
        @Html.Partial("PartialView", Model.partialModel)       
</div>
```

If you're using Razor, you can also user RenderPartial.

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName")  //html.partial

@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName");  }  //html.RenderPartial
```